# Sibling components trying to update the same parent state is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm working on making the rows of a table expand on the click of a button when the context of a cell do not fit.

I achieved this functionality but I have an issue with storing the largest height of the cell whom contents do not fit.

When I click the expand button I call a function that clones deep the state which then I assign the height to the id of that row in that state. This state is being declared in the same component where the functions are declared which are then passed as props to the cells.

The problem I have which I cant seem to understand why is that when I have two cells in a row whom contents do not fit, the height being saved is always the second one. I am making checks in the function to make sure it does not save the smaller height, but what is happening is that when the function is called for the second cell, the check is comparing with the default height, rather than the height of the previous cell.

This to me means that the state is not updating by the time the second cell calls the function, even though the state is declared in the parent component.

Anyone has any clue as to what might be the issue?

Comment: Can you add a sample code to explain the issue in more detail?

Comment: State updates are async and batched sometimes. Post code please. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot#rendering-takes-a-snapshot-in-time